Is it possible to serve PHPMyAdmin from a route with PHP Router?
A fresh install with composer create-project phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin will work out-of-the-box by visiting localhost:8080/phpmyadmin (served with php -S localhost:8080).
However, a typical setup with PHP Router seems to not work.
Here's my routes setup:
// routes.php

<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/router.php';

get('/', 'index.php');
get('/phpmyadmin', 'phpmyadmin/index.php');

This results in a ReferenceError to some JS that's not being loaded.
I also tried get('/phpmyadmin', 'phpmyadmin'); , as well as get('/phpmyadmin', 'phpmyadmin/'); to no avail.
Is there a way to use PHPMyAdmin in conjunction with PHP Router?

I think my recommendation would be to install it as its own thing that your router is completely unaware of. A standard folder install should work just fine. You could still do this with composer, too, just not part of your main project. Doing this will also make it so that your project's dependencies don't conflict with phpMyAdmin's.

Unfortunately, this did not work with PHP's built in server. Same ReferenceError issue. It did, however, work with Apache. I'll put it up now.

Problem circumvented: Using an Apache server instead of php -S localhost:8080 routes.php seemed to have done the trick, for some reason.
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
<Directory "absolute/path/to/project/root">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    DirectoryIndex routes.php
</Directory>

Optionally:
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex routes.php index.php index.html
</IfModule>

I also created a gist in case someone also comes across this problem - just replace index.php with routes.php, or, conversely, rename routes.php to index.php.
I'll leave the answer open, in case someone comes up with an actual fix.
